# Google Provider OAuthCallback error when using signin callback function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I am working with next.js with next-auth googleProvider. I wrote my code on localhost, but I get an error when I sign in.
I have done all the steps related to google cloud:

- OAuth client
- Authorized redirect URIs
- - http://localhost:3000
- - http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google
- Authorized JavaScript origins
- - http://localhost:3000

Set in project(Their values are cleared here):

- GOOGLE_ID
- GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
- MONGODB_URI
- NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
- NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000
- NEXTAUTH_SECRET

The problem I faced is it Google API returns an error when trying to sign in. Once the signing was done correctly and after signing out, this error is given in the sign-in.
The symptom is like below

- it prints "Try signing in with a different account." in the browser
- it returns an error message like below in the server

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error outgoing request timed out after 3500ms {
  error: {
    message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms',
    stack: 'RPError: outgoing request timed out after 3500ms\n' +
      '    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/request.js:115:19)\n' +
      '    at async Issuer.discover (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:135:30)\n' +
      '    at async openidClient (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:12:18)\n' +
      '    at async getAuthorizationUrl (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:88:20)\n' +
      '    at async Object.signin (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:21:30)\n' +
      '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:259:36)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:49:30)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:83:24)\n' +
      '    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:265:37)',
    name: 'RPError'
  },
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'outgoing request timed out after 3500ms'
}
```

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

import User from '@models/user';
import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session }) {
            // store the user id from MongoDB to session
            const sessionUser = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
            session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();

            return session;
        },
        async signIn({ account, profile, user, credentials }) {
            try {
                await connectToDB();

                // check if user already exists
                const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email });

                // if not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
                if (!userExists) {
                    await User.create({
                        email: profile.email,
                        username: profile.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(),
                        image: profile.picture,
                    });
                }

                return true
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error checking if user exists: ", error.message);
                return false
            }
        },
    }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```